# Есть ли у конструкции Switch Case оператор строгого соответствия

Tags: case, switch, php

```
switch($param){
    case true:
    $return ='YES';
    break;
    case false:
    $return ='NO';
    break;
}
```

Можно ли как нибудь сделать что бы конструкция реагировала только на строгие значения `false & true` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Есть костыль.

```
switch(true){
case ($param===$value1):
break;
case ($param===$value2):
break;
}
```

Comment: Вся фишка CASE в том чтобы он вычислял значение выражения один раз а далее его только сравнивал, в данном примере лучше использовать if ... elseif ... elseif ...

Comment: Отнюдь не всегда. 
http://phpswitch.com/

Answer (score 0):

Ну в таких случаях ИМХО нужно писать

```
$return = ($param) ? 'YES' : 'NO';
```

ну а если там нужно не только значение $return то как в ответе выше